# Change properties panel of the model in Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

How can I filter the list of properties of my model and hide some properties from the properties panel?

Answer (score 1):

You should be reading [this article](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/adding-custom-properties-property-panel) from Augusto. The article shows you how to add properties, but the principle is the same to remove/filter properties from the list. Here is some of the API you may need:

```
/**
* Adds the given properties to the display panel.
* @param {Array} properties - An array of properties, each property represented as {displayName: name, displayValue: value}.
* @param {Object=} [options] - An optional dictionary of options.  Currently unused.
*/
PropertyPanel.prototype.setProperties = function (properties, options) 

/**
* Adds a property to this panel.  The property is defined by its name, value, and category.  The
* add will fail if a property with the same name, value, and category already exists.
*
* @param {string} name - The name of the property to add.
* @param {string} value - The value of the property to add.
* @param {string} category - The category of the property to add.
* @param {Object=} [options] - An optional dictionary of options.
* @param {boolean} [options.localizeCategory=false] - When true, localization is attempted for the given category
* @param {boolean} [options.localizeProperty=false] - When true, localization is attempted for the given property
* @returns {boolean} - true if the property was added, false otherwise.
*/
PropertyPanel.prototype.addProperty = function (name, value, category, options)

/**
* Returns whether this property panel currently has properties.
*
* @returns {boolean} - true if there are properties to display, false otherwise.
*/
PropertyPanel.prototype.hasProperties = function ()

/**
* Removes a property from this panel.  The property is defined by its name, value, and category.
*
* @param {string} name - The name of the property to remove.
* @param {string} value - The value of the property to remove.
* @param {string} category - The category of the property to remove.
* @param {Object=} [options] - An optional dictionary of options.  Currently unused.
* @returns {boolean} - true if the property was removed, false otherwise.
*/
PropertyPanel.prototype.removeProperty = function (name, value, category, options)
```

Comment: Can I remove category using removeProperty?

Comment: @DanilaEremenko, to Remove a category, you need to remove all properties from that category